# Is mock data in unit tests feasible?

Tags: java, unit-tests

I am implementing an abstraction layer that basically translates Hibernate criteria into my data model. I am trying to apply TDD but test fixtures are Hibernate criteria objects, hard to get without a persistence provider. This leads me in a situation where unit tests are harder to write than integration tests, a very big smell.

Could mocking be an option? I am somehow afraid to introduce errors (the dreadful mystery guest) by mocking wrong.

My aim is of course to get unit tests before integration tests. How to overcome or mitigate this issue?

Comment: Can you give more details on why is hard to create the fixtures (maybe some code example)? At principle you can simply create these objects without needing a database https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_criteria_queries.htm

Comment: Isn't a database mandatory to get an hibernate `Session` object? I was sure about that, let me check..

Comment: The tag's already in the tags, it doesn't belong in the title. See e.g. "Should I use tags in titles?" on https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/tagging. @Prome you certainly shouldn't be editing them _into_ titles.

Comment: The problem could be that the methods are not interface driven, change the params to an interface then the test itself can implement it anyway it wants.  Short of it is don't force params to pass in instantiated objects of a particular class type, rather change them to the interface which represents the class (properties, methods etc.)